# Import jmp file into r

Tags: r, import, sas-jmp

I'm looking for a method to directly import a JMP file ("filename.jmp") into R. So far, all I can find are suggestions to first convert the JMP file to another format (either xpt, csv, etc.) and then import that new file into R.

Does anyone know of a method or way to import a JMP file without converting it first to another format?

My JMP application license has expired which is why I want to import these files into R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of September 2018 there is no R function that reads JMP files. `foreign::read.xport()`  and `Hmisc::sasexport.get()` work with SAS export files. The [haven package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/haven.pdf) can be used to read SAS files, but not JMP files.

A nice summary of import and export approaches in R is included in the [rio package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html) vignette.

A hack would be to install the [30 day trial version of JMP](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/offers/free-trial.html), convert all the data files you need to read in R to SAS data sets, and then use `haven::read_sas()` to read the data into R.

Alternately, one could use JMP to save the files as CSV files, per this help reference on the [JMP support website](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/14/save-as-a-csv-file.shtml), and then use `read.csv()` or readr::read_csv()` to read the data in R.

Comment: Echoing the use of the free trial route. The format appears to be proprietary and most solutions outside of R seem to be controlling SAS/JMP via Windows DCOM or converting to another format (and all the R solutions seem to be convert to another format so they're readable or use the bridge inside SAS/JMP to use R functions).

Comment: Thank you very much for 1) confirming that there is no direct import option, and 2) providing the other suggestions. I have installed the trial version of JMP and I'm converting the needed files to CSV for import into R.